# How can I pass a PathVariable from my jsp form:select to my Spring controller?

Tags: spring, jsp

I am trying to pass the String value from a form:select part of a JSP in a @PathVariable to my controller. To my understanding, the given code should return the variable with the value, yet i always get the error: Required String parameter 'stringValue' is not present.

```
<div>
    <form:select path="strings" name="strings" items="${strings}" 
     id="strings" class="form-control" value="${selectedString}"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed after posting, that I gave the wrong id for my value.